# Translucent UITableViewCell for grouped UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to create a TRANSLUCENT grouped table view cell. In other words I want to see the grouped table view background pattern, but i don't want completely clear cells. I've seen a lot of questions about transparent cells but none address making translucent (only partially transparent) cells.

This is what I'm trying:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

And this is the result: 
[image]

It's almost right, except that the contentView of the cell extends beyond the rounded corners of the grouped cell.

**SOLVED** by using a transparent image and setting the cell's background view. Would have still liked to do it programmatically though, so if anyone has a solution, I will gladly accept it.

**SOLVED Part II** Can also be done by setting backgroundView to a new UIView, that has the desired background color and rounded corners via QuartzCore's setCornerRadius call to the view's layer property.

Comment: the backgroundView property takes a UIView so just there is no need to use the image. Just create a view with the colour you want and set its alpha to the transparency that works for you.

Comment: This is basically the same as what I tried initially (there is no difference assigning backgroundView to a new UIView or simply assigning a color to it directly). No rounded corners.

Comment: BUT, it occurred to me it can be achieved with a QuartzCore setCornerRadius call :)

Comment: Just seen another question related to this... could you have SOLVED part III by simply removing the backgroundView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, the code that I ended up using was:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //...  

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [[bgView layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.25f]];
    cell.backgroundView = bgView;

    //...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you have one cell in section. Otherwise looks quirky.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, with the addition of adding an extra bit of height in the -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:   Previous version of the code had been using one section per data item instead, just to take advantage of the built-in transparency between sections!

Answer (score 3):

This should be all you need:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: This is the right solution. Besides you should set textLabel backgroundColor to clearColor: cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];