# Translucent effect on UITableView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, ios7

Hi i need some help from you guys, i'm new in iOS development and i started my app in iOS 6, so i'm trying to implement the new translucent effect in my UITableView.

The problem is that i cant make it, i'm shure is possible because is in the behavior of the the new spot light.

I'v tried to set the caracteristics of the UITableView, alpha, opaque, bacground and nothing seems to work.

Can you point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601654/translucent-uitableviewcell-for-grouped-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK!! This is what i was looking for, the first solution was OK but it didn't make the right effect, which is Gaussian Blur, so the first thing you have to do is to add a new .m and .h file with the code i'm writing here, then you have to make and screen shoot, use the desired effect and add it to your view, then your UITable has to be transparent (as in the previous answer), you can play with applyBlurWithRadius and with [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5], to archive the desired effect, this call works with any UIImage.

For this to work you have to add the next libraries:

Acelerate.framework,UIKit.framework,CoreGraphics.framework

I hope you like it.

Happy coding.

**Usage:**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];

UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
viewImage = [viewImage applyLightEffect];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**UIImage+ImageEffects.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (ImageEffects)

- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage;

@end
```

**UIImage+ImageEffects.m**

```
#import "cGaussianEffect.h"
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#import <float.h>


@implementation UIImage (ImageEffects)


- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:1 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:0.82];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:1 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.11 alpha:0.73];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:1 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    const CGFloat EffectColorAlpha = 0.6;
    UIColor *effectColor = tintColor;
    int componentCount = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(tintColor.CGColor);
    if (componentCount == 2) {
        CGFloat b;
        if ([tintColor getWhite:&b alpha:NULL]) {
            effectColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:b alpha:EffectColorAlpha];
        }
    }
    else {
        CGFloat r, g, b;
        if ([tintColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:NULL]) {
            effectColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:EffectColorAlpha];
        }
    }
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:10 tintColor:effectColor saturationDeltaFactor:-1.0 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    if (self.size.width < 1 || self.size.height < 1) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: invalid size: (%.2f x %.2f). Both dimensions must be >= 1: %@", self.size.width, self.size.height, self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!self.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: %@", self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (maskImage && !maskImage.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: %@", maskImage);
        return nil;
    }

    CGRect imageRect = { CGPointZero, self.size };
    UIImage *effectImage = self;

    BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    BOOL hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.) > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    if (hasBlur || hasSaturationChange) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(effectInContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(effectInContext, 0, -self.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(effectInContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

        vImage_Buffer effectInBuffer;
        effectInBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;
        effectOutBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectOutContext);

        if (hasBlur) {
            CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            NSUInteger radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if (radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1;
            }
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
        }
        BOOL effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = NO;
        if (hasSaturationChange) {
            CGFloat s = saturationDeltaFactor;
            CGFloat floatingPointSaturationMatrix[] = {
                    0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                    0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                    0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                                  0,                    0,                    0,  1,
            };
            const int32_t divisor = 256;
            NSUInteger matrixSize = sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix)/sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[0]);
            int16_t saturationMatrix[matrixSize];
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
                saturationMatrix[i] = (int16_t)roundf(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor);
            }
            if (hasBlur) {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
                effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = YES;
            }
            else {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
            }
        }
        if (!effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if (effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

    if (hasBlur) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        if (maskImage) {
            CGContextClipToMask(outputContext, imageRect, maskImage.CGImage);
        }
        CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, effectImage.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    if (tintColor) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code snippet

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: THANKS!! this is what i needed, but now i'm getting empty transparent lines at the end of the UITable, i'm stil lost on this.

Answer (score 0):

This solve all my issues, dValue is the JSON from where i'm getting the count (all the stuff to fill the UITable), so when i have less than 7 items i just change values of the custom cell to Nil and keep the background blurred effect.

You can change the effect by changing the color.

I hope this will be helpful.

Happy coding.

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //Change the number of rows.
    return (dValue.count <= 7) ? 7 : dValue.count;
}

(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //To avoid editing.
    return NO;
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Get JSON data.
    NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_JsonConfigFile ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];

    NSDictionary *dConfiguration =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //Get custom cell.
    vcCellEventsController *cCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (dValue.count > indexPath.row) {
        dValue = [[dConfiguration objectForKey:sButtonType] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Change color and set transparency.
        cCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
        //Fill all the custom stuff.
        cCell.ivImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dValue objectForKey:@"Image"]];
        cCell.tcText.text = [dValue objectForKey:@"Label"];
    }
    else {
        //Avoid user interaction and change the accessory. 
        [cCell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [cCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        //Change color and set transparency.
        cCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
        //Set all the custom stuff to nil.
        cCell.ivImage.image = Nil;
        cCell.tcText.text = Nil;
    }

   return cCell;
}
```